# How do I disable these strange contrast hotkeys?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> my screen changes contrast/. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> sets it to "Default" while <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> cycles between "Normal", "Light", "Contrast", "Bright", "Vivid", "Intense", "Dimmed", and "Opaque".

I have no idea what caused these hotkeys to start behaving this way, it's been this way for as long as I can remember. I just can't stand the behavior any longer and want to make it stop. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your graphics card/video adapter options for disabling hotkeys.

Comment: I looked in the NVIDIA Control Panel for hotkey settings and couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's not a default Windows setting, so has to be something extraneous like (driver) software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was caused by a program called "Game Companion" which I had previously used to force games that didn't natively support borderless windowed mode into that display configuration. It was running at startup and had hotkeys for gamma adjustment.